# Two Different servers and websites on One IP

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, mac-osx-server

I'd Like to set up two different websites on one IP address using two different servers. Right now we are using Apache for our one Mac Server and it forwards correctly both to the pyhsical IP address as well as the domain. We'd like to add another domain to a new computer also running Leopard + Apache

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to setup a reverse proxy on a box in front of both web servers then.  You can use Apache with mod_proxy, nginx, squid, etc. to do this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy

Answer (score 1):

You can use either SQUID or Apache to redirect or rewrite based on URI or hostname conditions.